# Compound Interest Program Syntax Error

Tags: java

I have the below code to run a compound interest program but I do not know why it is not working. Eclipse is giving me the error message: "The value of the local variable amount is not used."

```
package loops;

public class CompoundInterest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("How much did you put into the bank?");
        double deposit = IO.readDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the bank's interest rate?");
        double rate = IO.readDouble();
        System.out.println("How many times will it compound?");
        double compound = IO.readDouble();
        System.out.println("How many years?");
        double years = IO.readDouble();

        for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++){
            double amount = deposit * Math.pow(1+(rate/compound), years*compound);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Since you never produce any output, it is warning you that your computation is all wasted electron movement.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you repeat exactly the same calculation 20 times?  Using the formula that you've used means you only have to do the calculation once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is a compiler warning (not an error). It's technically "legal" to have variables you don't actually use, but the compiler's telling you that it's probably a mistake. In this case, as others have indicated, you assign a value to `amount` but you never actually do anything with it.

As a general tip, it's helpful to pay close attention to the text of the warning - in this case, it was what it said (you don't do anything with the `amount` variable). Eric Lippert has an extremely helpful [article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) available on how to debug small programs that I recommend taking a look at when you get a chance. (His explanation of "rubber-duck debugging" alone makes the article more than worth the read).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a statement inside your loop to use `amount` as -

```
for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++){
    double amount = deposit * Math.pow(1+(rate/compound), years*compound);
    System.out.println(amount); // just a type of use
}
```

The warning is to notify that the amount calculated in the statement is being not in use. Once used(even for displaying as above) the warning shall go away.